# Check if a point is contained by any polygon stored in PostGis

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm using PostGIS and I've created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, poly geometry(POLYGON));
```

Inserted a polygon:

```
INSERT INTO test(poly) VALUES(ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POLYGON((0.0 0.0, 0.0 10.0, 10.0 0.0, 10.0 10.0, 0.0 0.0))'));
```

Now I'd like to check if POINT(5 5) is within any of the polygons:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE ST_Contains(poly, ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(5 5)'));
id | poly 
----+------
(0 rows)
```

I don't understand where the problem is. Shouldn't it return the inserted polygon? There must be some trivial mistake in my statement.

Comment: If that's the exact statement, the vertex order of the Polygon is wrong, making it invalid.

Comment: @geozelot yes, that's the problem. I've copied the INSERT statement from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367822/issue-with-st-contains-and-st-within-in-postgis Please post that as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertex order in

> 'SRID=4326;POLYGON((0.0 0.0, 0.0 10.0, **10.0 0.0, 10.0 10.0**, 0.0 0.0))'

is mixed up; this will result in a self-intersecting (invalid) Polygon, and

> [...] in the case of  invalid geometries [...] the result is always false regardless or not defined. -[docs](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html)

It has to be

```
'SRID=4326;POLYGON((0.0 0.0, 0.0 10.0, 10.0 10.0, 10.0 0.0, 0.0 0.0))'
```

to represent a (projected) rectangle.

---

Bonus:

Assuming that we don't have floating point precision errors, your query would also return falsey for a valid triangular shape (derived off your invalid Polygon above) that passes through your Point, since containment requires that

> [...] at least one point of the interior of B lies in the interior of A. -[same docs](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html)

*The docs provide a link on [Subtleties of OGC Covers, Contains, Within](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2007/06/subtleties-of-ogc-covers-spatial.html?m=1) with a few insights.*

For Point-in-Polygon, `ST_Intersects` is the way to go, and for Point-in-BBox you can use the `&&` operator.